# How can I require auth to access some components in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jwt

I'm new to react but i have previously worked on server side rendering websites

My objective is to make a website where at first only a sign-up, login page is shown and if the login was successful the user would be able to access other pages

I'm using and api which provide jwt tokens and jwt refresh tokens for authentication, the main token expires in 1hr and i need to auto generate new token by then in the background without the user knowing

So how should i go about implementing this any example code would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

This site is about helping to solve specific programming issues, noone will write your app for you. The idea is to acquire the token via authentication, persist it in browser (local/session storage), then attach it as auth header to every api request. For refreshing the token implement some `setInterval`.